# Web Components - Qual a diferença entre Polymer e ReactJS?

Tags: polymer, react

Com avanço da web, agora temos também os web componentes.

Google criou e mantém um framework com nome de Polymer, apesar de não ter muita compatibilidade com vários navegadores.

Na outra ponta temos o ReactJS do Facebook, que também cria esses "componentes".

Qual a diferença entre as duas tecnologias? Ou elas tem a mesma finalidade?

Comment: uma pergunta muito parecida foi feitano [Stack Over Flow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342288/pros-and-cons-of-facebooks-react-vs-web-components-polymer) e foi fechada por se basear somente em opniões.

Comment: Rafael, eu cheguei até esse link, mas fiquei bem confuso, resumindo, eu só queria saber se eles tem muito de diferente, ou tem o mesmo objetivo, que é criar web components

Comment: Rod, um dos comentários tem um link, onde a pessoa diz ter colocado a resposta, está [aqui](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225400/pros-and-cons-of-facebooks-react-vs-web-components-polymer/237762#237762). Talvez ajude!

Comment: Resposta dele, é muito tedenciosa, ele só reclama do reactjs e de ser bonito ou feio a escrita de jhx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bom, as duas tem objetivos diferentes, e em algum ponto podem até se cruzar.

**O Polymer** tem como objetivo encapsular o html, js e css utilizando a spec de [importação de .html](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-imports/), [shadow DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) e [componentes web.](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/)

**Importação de arquivo html (html import)**

ex: Adicionando um menu html em um site sem importação de html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="menu.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
<div class="menu">...</div>
```

ex: Adicionando o mesmo menu com importação de html

```
<link rel="import" href="menu.html">
```

Na verdade é bem simples,importando o arquivo html podemos criar uma pagina ( como no ex. a menu.html ) e fazer com que ela importe o html, css e js do Manu.

Com isso, basta importar a pagina para utilizar o componente ( elemento html )  e ela importa os demais arquivos.

**Shadow DOM**

O shadow DOM cria um novo contexto para o componente separando ele do contexto da pagina, com isso você não precisa se preocupar por exemplo colisões de id ou de css de fora do contexto.

Então na hora de criar um elemento com ID 'item', não se preocupe com a possibilidade de ter outro elemento com esse mesmo ID dentro da pagina onde o componente será renderizado.

**Componente HTML (web component)**

O componente html de forma resumida é uma maneira de encapsular a criação do componente através de tags html.
Ao invés de ter que criar o html e depois executar o  javascript:

```
<div id="menu"></div>
$("#menu").criaMenu({});
```

Basta registar o componente e depois chamar a tag.

```
<meuMenu />
```

**O React** por sua vez, não tem a menor preocupação  (pelo menos por enquanto) de organizar seus arquivos utilizando a importação de html nem a criação de web components.
O objetivo do react está em criar componentes html/javascript e renderizar ele de forma performática no browser utilizando o virtual DOM.

O Virtual DOM é um mecanismo de diff, que faz toda a manipulação de html acontecer na memória antes de ser renderizada no DOM, fazendo isso é possível verificar o que já esta criado e alterar apenas o que foi alterado.

Answer (score 5):

Como nunca usei nenhuma das duas bibliotecas, respondo com o que entendo ser a diferença básica entre elas: enquanto o Polymer é uma tentativa de dar suporte imediato às novas especificações do W3C que, em conjunto, são chamadas de [Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/), o ReactJS é um framework totalmente independente dessas especificações.

O objetivo das duas é semelhante (criar componentes encapsulados e reaproveitáveis para uso em aplicações web), mas a maneira como cada biblioteca trabalha parece ser completamente diferente.