# Onde salvar o JS de um site

Tags: javascript

Quando desenvolvo um site, sempre salvo ele dentro de uma pasta chamada **js**, e geralmente o nome do arquivo é **acoes.js**.
O que acontece, é que eu chamo esse arquivo em cada página. E as vezes, eu crio uma função para determinada página, e quando estou em outra, como não há nem *classe* nem a *id* contendo essa função, dá erro no console.

Eu sempre tenho que verificar se existe ou não, dessa forma:

```
if($('#MINHA_ID').length>0){ MINHA FUNÇÃO});
```

Eu fazendo essa verificação, de que essa *id* está sendo usada ou não nessa página, não há problema.

Essa é a forma correta? ou devo fazer um **js** separado pra cada página?

Comment: O ideal é ter um arquivo js com funções genéricas para serem utilizadas em diversas páginas, fazendo assim o reuso de código. Porém caso tenha necessidade de criar algo específico para uma página, pode criar uma função na própria página.

Comment: Poderia fornecer um exemplo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução ideal é ter um objeto com todas as funções que precisa, aí pode ter num ficheiro unico. Alternativa é ter as funções no espaço global, mas é boa prática não poluir o espaço global.

Essas funções só devem ser chamadas quando necessário, ao invés de ter código misturado que corre de uma ponta à outra.

Sempre que possível passe tudo o que a função precisa como parâmetro da função, aí vai estar a dar todos os ingredientes que precisa sem depender do que existe no DOM.

Exemplo, dentro do seu ficheiro JS:

```
var Site = {

    start: function(){
        Site.Cookie = new Hash.Cookie('selections-005', {duration: 365});
    },
    menu: function(li){
        // acões especificas do menu
    },
    uncheck: function(input, force){
        // outro método que gere input[type=checkbox] por exemplo
    },
    check: function(input){
        // outro método que gere input[type=checkbox] por exemplo
    },
    selectAll: function(){
        $('#download tr.check').each(Site.check);
    },
    selectNone: function(){
        $('#download tr.check').each(Site.uncheck);
    }
};

Site.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Tenho quase certeza que a maioria das respostas será baseado em opiniões, e essa pergunta poderá ser fechada. Mas...

Não tem nada de errado em fazer essa verificação `if($('#MINHA_ID').length>0){ MINHA FUNÇÃO});`... Na verdade **eu acho** que sempre deve ser feita em conteúdo que não seja comum a todas as páginas, como `header` e `footer`.

---

### Baseado em Fatos

A **maior vantagem** de criar arquivos `js` para cada página, é que não é necessário a transmissão de dados desnecessários, ou seja, você não precisa enviar um bloco de código inútil para o usuário. Em computadores essa vantagem parece até "boba", mas em celulares onde os usuários muitas vezes tem planos com limite de transferência isso é **muito válido**.

---

### Baseado em Opinião

Antigamente eu tinha o hábito de guardar tudo em um mesmo arquivo, mas hoje eu acredito que a melhor maneira de organizar os arquivos JavaScript é ter um arquivo principal, por exemplo `main.js`,  para todas as páginas e arquivos específicos para cada página e chamo-os de acordo com a página carregada, por exemplo `home.js` ou `contato.js` (mas as vezes (por preguiça) nem crio os arquivos, deixo-os na página mesmo: `<script>...blá blá blá...</script>`). E ainda ter um arquivo só para funções, que eu costumo chamar de `util.js` ou `funcoes.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade esse problema que você está encontrando tem sido bastante discutido,e aparentemente a solução oficial para esse problema é a utilização de [web components](http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/).

Acho que no seu caso vale a pena dar uma olhada no [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/), e [aqui no stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26353/web-components-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-polymer-e-reactjs) também tem uma pergunta a respeito disso.